# My Sessions Flash Messages are not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am using FLASH in Laravel to display small notification here is how my function looks like:

```
public function movetotrash($id){

        $page = Pages::where('id', $id) -> first();
        $page -> active = 0;
        //$page -> save();
        \Session::flash('flash_message', 'Post has been successfully moved to trash');
        return redirect('pages');
 }
```

Here is how my View looks like:

```
<div class="col-md-12">

                    @if(Session::has('flash_message'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                                {{Session::get('flash_message')}}
                        </div>
                    @endif
</div>
```

And here is how my Route looks like:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard.dashboard');
});

Route::get('pages/trash', 'PagesController@trashpage');

Route::get('pages/movetotrash/{id}', 'PagesController@movetotrash');

Route::resource('pages', 'PagesController');
```

Do i need to call some library in my controller for `Session` to work?

Thank you! (in advance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From laravel docs : https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing

> Any routes not placed within the web middleware group will not have
>   access to **sessions** and CSRF protection, so make sure any routes that
>   need these features are placed within the group. Typically, you will
>   place most of your routes within this group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
     //all routes
});
```

Put your routes inside middleware and your problem will solve.

Comment: Ohk! Let me try this.